# Forward-slash-enclosed Bash script function name(?)

Tags: bash, shell-script

What is this???

```
/\[*\]/ {
      inFoo = ($1 == "["foo"]")
      next
    }
```

It looks like a function because of the enclosing braces, but what on earth is that before the opening brace??? Some sort of regex'ed function name? I've never been great at Bash scripting, but this is altogether indecipherable.

There's a similar one, but it's body is too large (and potentially sensitive) for me to post:

```
/.*/ {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: The executable should start `#!/usr/bin/awk` not `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: BTW, the `/.*/` isn't needed - it matches anything and everything (including nothing, or an empty line).  the `awk` code would work exactly the same without the regex.  In other words, it's like using `if 1==1 { do something }' when just `{do something}` is equivalent.

Comment: the first rule matches zero-or-more `[` characters, followed by a `]`.  That may do something useful (depends on the input data and what the author is trying to match) but it's more likely to be a typo - perhaps a missing `.` before the `*`, which would make the regex match everything from a `[` to a `]`.  even better would be `\[[^]]*\]` which would only match everything inside a matched-pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain that you posted `bash` code? It looks to me like part of an `awk` script. If it is `awk` code, then the forward slashes delimit a regex address rule, ie. process the `{...}` for all lines matching the regex. The rule matches all lines that have an open bracket, followed by some text, followed by a close bracket.

Comment: I believe it is a bash script: the extension is `.sh` and the top of the file has `#!/bin/sh` - that means it's a bash script, no?

Comment: File extensions are ignored and bad practice, but the `#!/bin/sh` (if on first line) will make is shell code.

Comment: Does it have some shell code, before this code?

Comment: I see what's going on: I think you're right: these were chunks of awk code embedded within the bash script. Prior to the noted code, I see `echo "$(awk -v fubar=$fubar '` (note the absence of closing double-quote. Is this standard practice? I've never seen bash and awk code in the same file before (but I seem to be an eternal n00b for all things Linux)

Comment: @StoneThrow - "Standard practice"? All it's doing is removing newline characters from `awk` output. It might be a bug.

Comment: @StoneThrow it's entirely normal - yes, standard practice - for shell scripts to have embedded scripts written in awk, sed, perl, and more.   shell's purpose is to run other programs and tie them together with pipes, conditionals, loops, command and process substitutions, etc.  BTW, both single- and double- quotes can extend across multiple lines so the "missing" close quote on some later line.

Comment: @StoneThrow: What you call *embedding* is not some special magic, but simply derives from the fact that in virtually any reasonable programming language, you can run an external program as a subprocess. Hence you just need to define a string in your (shell-)program, representing the external (awk-)program, and then run awk as a child process. This concept is by no mean restricted to shell programs, though in practice, it is much more often used from shell scripts than from other languages.

Comment: Thanks cas & user1934428 - your answers help me better understand the use and scope of Bash scripting.